# getURL in RCurl problem behind firewall R

Tags: r, curl, geturl, rcurl

I'm behind hospital firewalls and usually have to use `setInternet2(T)` for R to access the net properly. However running my code (that works perfectly at home) results in

```
curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
  Could not resolve host: www.cnn.com; Host not found
```

Is it at all possible to work around this?

regards,

//M

Comment: We need more info. What code produces this message? Does anything work over the internet from work? Does x=getURL("h ttp://www.cnn.com/") give the same error message? Is that what you are doing? Looks like an issue with DNS lookups. (not sure how to do URLs in this edit box so remove space from http above)

Comment: x=getURL("www.cnn.com") produces the response above. Internet works fine when I use setInternet2(T)-ie I can use install.packages etc...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like RCurl doesn't use the same proxy settings as R (and so setting internet2 doesn't help), you need to set them manually, with the `curlSetOpt` command:

`curl <- getCurlHandle()`

`curlSetOpt(.opts = list(proxy = '<address>:<port>'), curl = curl)`

`ans <- getURL('http://www.cnn.com', curl = curl)`

Comment: Looks promising if I only could figure out how to access the proxy settings in R. Is there a function that would retrieve these settings that subsequently could be fed to curlSetOpt??